# Is it possible to express $\sin(\frac{k\pi}{4})$ as something of the form $(-1)^{f(k)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometric-integrals, trigonometric-series

For example $\cos(k\pi)=(-1)^k$ similarily, $\sin(\frac{k\pi}{2})=(-1)^\frac{k-1}{2}$ when k is odd, and 0 otherwise. Is there a similar representation for $\sin(\frac{k\pi}{4})$

Comment: isnt enough just using log?

Comment: How is $\sin(\frac{2\pi}2)=(-1)^{(2-1)/2}$?

Comment: The $sin(\frac{kpi}{4})=(-1)^{(k-1)/2}$ when k is odd, otherwise its zero. Forgot to specify.

Comment: No, certainly not. When $k=1$, $|\sin(\pi/4)| = \sqrt{2}/2$, but $|(-1)^{f(k)}| = 1$.

Comment: @RomanTatofski I think you should have kept denominator as 2 in your last comment.